# ASP.NET Web API body value restriction

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I'm studying ASP.NET Web API, but somewhere in the explanation about complex types that comes from the request body the author confuses me:

[PROFESSIONAL ASP.NET MVC 4](http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/WroxTitle/Professional-ASP-NET-MVC-4.productCd-111834846X.html): Chapter 11 - ASP.NET Web API

> "[..] complex types (everything else) are taken from the body. There is
>   an additional restriction as well: Only a single value can come from
>   the body, and that value must represent the entirety of the body.
>   [...]"
>
> Brad Wilson

What does his mean with this **"single value can come from the body"**? The API formatters can parse only a single **type of object** from the body? Could you illustrate this by example?

Comment: Probably author means that body musu be in exact correspondence with expected controller's input. Just necessary data and nothing more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **Only a single value can come from the body**

Assume you have a request body like this.

`{"Id":12345, "FirstName":"John", "LastName":"West"}`

You want this JSON to be bound to a parameter of type like this.

```
public class Employee
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

The action method can be like `void Post(Employee emp)`. And it cannot be like this - `void Post(Employee john, Employee duplicateJohn)`. Only a single value can come from the body.

> **and that value must represent the entirety of the body**

Assume you have the same request body like this.

`{"Id":12345, "FirstName":"John", "LastName":"West"}`

And you have two DTOs like this.

```
public class Identifier
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class Name
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

You cannot have an action method like `void Post(Identifier id, Name name)` and expect the body to be bound partially to both the parameters. Body in its entirety must be bound to only **one** value. So, having a class like

```
public class Employee
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

and binding the request body in its entirety to one value like `void Post(Employee emp)` is only allowed.

Comment: Thank you! I Twitted to Brad and he said that you rock! Much more clear now!

Answer (score 1):

This basically means that you cannot have multipart body that describes more than one complex type. Say if you have a `User` type, the entire body must describe that `User` type and not `User` + `ShoppingChart` types.

Valid body for `User` type:

```
{
   "id" : "1",
   "username" : "someuser"
}
```

Invalid body for `User` type:

```
{
   "user" : {
      "id" : "1",
      "username" : "someuser"
   },

   "shoppingCart" : {
      "cartId" : "1",
      "items" : "5"
   }
}
```

Of course, you can create a new complex type like `UserAndShoppingCart` (which uses user and shopping cart classes as properties) and now the invalid body will be valid and deserializable for this new type.

Comment: I Twitted to Brad and he said that you rock! I got the another, just because he put much more enfort in the awsear! Anyway Thank you!